# SSIS - Upgrade from 2005 to 2008 - How to set a project property when I don't have a project

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssis, 64-bit, oledb

I have about 160 SSIS packages that I'm trying to upgrade from 2005 to 2008.

When I run SSISUpgrade.exe on them, I get the following error messages on many of the packages:

```
Error 0xc0209303: ...: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDB_NOPROVIDER_64BIT_ERROR.  The requested OLE DB provider MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered -- perhaps no 64-bit provider is available.  
enter code here`Error code: 0x00000000.
    An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".
```

[This fellow says](http://blog.davyknuysen.be/2008/08/26/import-excel-files-with-sql-server-integration-services-on-a-64-bit-server/) that to fix this I need to set the run64bitruntime debugging property to False.

However each of these packages exists outside of a project file.  How can I set this property without having a project file?

Comment: They're outside of a project file because each package is set to encrypt sensitive data with a password and when I tried putting them all in a package, when I opened it in Visual studio, it prompted me for the password 160 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if I turned off the check box to validate when running SSISUpgrade.exe it seemed to convert everything ok.

Then I just have to call the packages using the 32 bit dtexec found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn

I guess that's good enough for me.

Comment: Phew, I'm glad I ran into this!  Had the exact same problem... I didn't even think of the fact that there was likely a 32-bit version of dtexec sitting around on the system.  Excellent!